# Lebesgue and Riemann integral

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I'm asked to discuss the existence of Riemann and Lebesgue integral of the function:
$$
F(t)=
\int ^{\infty}_0 e^{-xt}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx, \quad t\geq 0.
$$

Please, I need the steps to follow, a routemap to discuss it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $\left|\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right|\leq 1$ for $x\ne 0$ so

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|e^{-xt}\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx\leq\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}dx=\frac{1}{t}<\infty
\end{align*}
so the Lebesgue integral exists. In particular, by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem we have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{u\uparrow\infty,~v\downarrow 0}\int_{v}^{u}e^{-xt}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=\lim_{u\uparrow\infty,~v\downarrow 0}\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{[v,u]}(x)e^{-xt}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx
\end{align*}
exists and equals to $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx$, so the Improper Riemann integral also exists.